# Use "||" to concat 2 "VARCHAR2(50)" type of columns return null sometimes in Oracle 12c Enterprise version

Tags: sql, oracle

**The detail is** - there are 2 columns in the same  table we need concat as a object name in the report. Both are 'VARCHAR2(50)' type, and we never met this kind of issue before until we upgraded to Oracle 12c.

**What I have done** - I tried searched in Oracle help center/google/bing/baidu... didn't find any related possbile questions and answers.

**My question is** => Have you anyone met this issue before? If so, what's your suggestion to fix this (I know we can use another approach to avoid this, so my expectation answer is 'fix', not 'avoid' - just want to figure this tricky issue out)?

- **PRODUCT**: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition
- **VERSION**: 12.2.0.1.0
- **STATUS**: 64bit Production

**Example:**

```
select A||'.'||B as C
...
...
from table_eg
```

------> we get C = `"."`

**Other Info**:

- columns are not null
- It cannot be reproduced 100% (compared with different data, different client to execute, different server, run it directly on server, different SQL script)
- Cannot reproduce it at all if just with simplest select + from script

Comment: i have run `select 'A'||'.'||'B' as C FROM DUAL` on Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0    i get `A.B`

Comment: Without a minimal reproducible example, this answer is not very likely to receive a relavant answer...

Comment: If you can identify a row in your table that produces this effect, maybe do `select A, dump(A), B, dump(B), A||'.'||B as C, dump(A||'.'||B) ... ` and add the result to your question - copying and pasting from your client, and formatting as code.

Answer (score 0):

You may have something like this?

```
create table junk( id number(2,0) not null
, a varchar2(50) not null
, b varchar2(50) not null );

insert into junk values( 1, ' ', ' ' );
insert into junk values( 2, 'x', 'y' );

commit;
```

Then

```
select id, a||'.'||b from junk;

        ID A||'.'||B                                                                                            
---------- ---------
         1  .                                                                                                   
         2 x.y
```